# Pipe into a shell/bash script from Web URL

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to download a script from URL, execute it, and pipe something into it - all with one command?

I have a shell script to which I can pipe stuff:

```
$ echo "Test Data" | do-stuff.sh
```

The script is moved to `http://example.com/do-stuff.sh`

Try to do something like this:

```
$ echo "Test Data" | ( curl -sfL http://example.com/do-stuff.sh | sh )
```

but it doesn't work. Data does not get piped into the script.

There is a workaround, but how to do it with one line without creating files?

```
$ curl -sfL http://example.com/do-stuff.sh > do-stuff.sh
$ chmod +x do-stuff.sh
$ echo "Test Data" | do-stuff.sh
$ rm do-stuff.sh
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```bash
echo "Test Data" | sh <(curl -sfL http://example.com/do-stuff.sh)
```

This needs to be run in bash or zsh or ksh due to the process substitition.

The reason why yours isn't working is that the `sh` process's stdin channel is already consumed by reading the source code, so you can't pipe data into it.

The process substitution acts like a file, so `sh` can get the source from the "file" and still read data from stdin.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting empty stream in the script, but it works with 'bash' instead of 'sh'.  Running in zsh v5.3 on Mac. Is that expected?

Comment: Sorry, looks like it was another issue caused by "echo -e" behavior in sh vs bash. Your solution work great.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the link with the script contains raw data without any transformation, then you can try this approach

```
echo "Test Data" | bash <(wget -O - http://example.com/do-stuff.sh)
```